# How to make sure a request function is complete before performing a method - javascript

Tags: javascript, request

When run, the code shown below logs "[]". I believe this is because the request function is not complete by the time the console.log method is called.

```
var urlArray = []
request('http://www.example.com', function (error, response, body) {
urlArray.push("example.com")
}
console.log(urlArray)
```

How do i put a conditional to make sure the request function is complete. the pseudo code would be:

```
if request function is complete{
  console.log(urlArray)
}
```

If this isn't the best way, what is?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply put the console.log in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you run it non-async, the line right after the request line will be executed when the request finishes, but thats not recommendable. Second, running async, ussually you get a callback or a promise depending the library you are using in order to perform the request, even if you use pure JS, you have the option to set callbacks for error and success states, that will be executed only after the request has received a response.
I recommend reading a bit about ajax and promises.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Having a look at the code you've provided, it seems that is just a concept or pseudocode, that will never run and throw all kind of errors and exceptions.